# Ask one out of two values in dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary

If I have a dictionary with two values for each key, how can I pick one value?

For example:

```
dict = {'Banana' : {'price': 7, 'Color' : "yellow"},
'Apple' : {'price' : 8, 'Color': "green"}, 'Orange' :{'price' : 6, 'Color': "orange"}}
```

When I want to know the price of each fruit, how can I ask that?

```
for i in range (len(dict)):
   dict[i][0]
```

Is this the right solution?

Comment: you mean this `[d[i]['price'] for i in d]` ?

Comment: Dictionaries are unordered, so you can't access values through numbers. Entries are accessible by key only.

Comment: Don't use `dict` as variable name, it shadows the built-in function `dict`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a different `for` loop, I doubt `in range` will work:

```
for fruit, data in dict.iteritems():
    print(fruit + " costs " + str(data['price']))
```

---

Edit to answer the comment:

`for i in range (len(d)): d.keys[i] == d.keys[i+1]:` and `for i in d.keys: d[i] == d[i+1]` won't work, you will have to write a bit more:

```
d = dict.keys()
for i in range(len(d)):
    if i+1 < len(d) and d[i] == d[i+1]:
        #do stuff
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer! I still have a question about the "in range": Can't I write something like the following? `  for i in range (len(d)):
          d.keys[i] == d.keys[i+1]: ` or do I have to write something like : ` for i in d.keys: d[i] == d[i+1]`

Comment: `keys` is a function, you need the parantheses.
`d[i]` will only work if `i` is one of the keys in the dictionary, same for `i+1`.

Answer (score 3):

This should work:

```
for fruit, info in dict.iteritems():
    print "%s: Colour %s - Price %d" % (fruit, info['Color'], info['price'])
```

Answer (score 0):

I totally agree the other answers. But if you works much with data, I suggest you use the '[pandas](http://pandas.pydata.org/)' library.

For your case, you can simply use the following code with pandas:

```
>>>import pandas
>>>df = pandas.DataFrame(dict).transopose()
Out:          
              Color price
     Apple    green     8
     Banana  yellow     7
     Orange  orange     6

>>>df['Color']
Out:
      Apple      green
      Banana    yellow
      Orange    orange
      Name: Color, dtype: object
```

Answer (score 0):

just iterate over keys.

```
 >>> for i in dict.keys():
...     print i, dict[i]['price']
... 
Orange 6
Banana 7
Apple 8
```

Answer (score 0):

Another option is [itervalues()](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#dict.itervalues) and [list comprehensions](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions)

```
>>> d = {'Banana' : {'price': 7, 'Color' : "yellow"},
... 'Apple' : {'price' : 8, 'Color': "green"}, 'Orange' :{'price' : 6, 'Color': "orange"}}
>>> [i['price'] for i in d.itervalues()]
[6, 7, 8]
```